# a valid alternative to mailto?

Tags: html, mailto

I maintain a site for an organization that contains 80+ contacts.  when I created this site I used *mailto:* to allow people to contact the required individual, which worked fine until just recently.

Now I find that when I click on the email link nothing happens or, as in my case, since I have MS Office, Windows tries to load Outlook which I don't want.    This is also affecting anyone browsing the site, I am receiving numerous notices that the email links are broken.   I know the addresses are valid because I can copy the address and send it manually with no problems.

```
I've searched the web and it seems that everyone recommends to NOT use *mailto:* and use to a form contact method, however, I am confused, I can figure out how to setup a contact form for one individual, I'm having a problem about how I would sync 80+ contacts to one Contact page.

I would really appreciate anyone who could point me in the right direction.   The site in this case is     [http://s-a-m-s.org/contact.php][1]
```

Thank you;

Greg

Comment: How are you expecting the computer to send an email?

Comment: It depends on your default mailto application. It can be MS Outlook, Gmail (within Chrome), Firefox etc. You don't have to worry about that, users can change it.

Comment: I was expecting my email carrier (Google) to open a blank email form with the recipients email address in the to: line like it used to do.    I apologize for the cryptic question above, I've added more to it for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an e-mail address in an anchor elements href attribute (`<a href="mailto: user@domain.com">`) to send e-mail is not a guarantee of sending e-mail.

The protocol `mailto` is user agent-specific which means that users with different browsers or devices will most definitely not have your desired outcome.

HTML is rendered by the clients browser which means that you can not control how your `mailto` protocol is being handled.

If you want to guarantee that your contacts can be contacted through your website you would have to resort to using another programming language.

You could then (for instance) loop through all your clients and build a contact form for each of your organisations contacts which the server would then send e-mails to. Contact your local developer to help you out with more specifics if HTML is your limit.